# serializer.is_valid with many=True

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a relatively simple question about how serializer.is_valid works when many=True in the Django REST framework.

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#deserializing-objects),

> When deserializing data, you always need to call is_valid() before
>   attempting to access the deserialized object. If any validation errors
>   occur, the .errors property will contain a dictionary representing the
>   resulting error messages.

If I am trying to serialize and save many docs at a time, and one of the docs is invalid but all the rest are valid, does serializer.is_valid return true or false? The docs seem to suggest serializer.is_valid should be false, but there isn't a concrete example that addresses this subtlety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing this myself, I will confirm that `serializer.is_valid() = False` if ANY of the documents are invalid. It only returns `True` if everything is valid.